TensorFlow InvalidArgumentError: Concatenation dimension mismatch in ConcatOp - Shapes do not match
I keep getting this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-d3274f3c8612> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Example usage:
----> 2 train(training_A, training_B, generator_g, generator_f, epochs, sample_A, testing_A, testing_B)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   5981 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name) -> NoReturn:
   5982   e.message += (" name: " + str(name if name is not None else ""))
-> 5983   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   5984 
   5985 

InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling Concatenate.call().

{{function_node __wrapped__ConcatV2_N_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} ConcatOp : Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal: shape[0] = [1,6,4,512] vs. shape[1] = [1,5,3,512] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

Arguments received by Concatenate.call():
  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 6, 4, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 5, 3, 512), dtype=float32)']

This is the output I am keep getting.
The code I am implementing is:
epochs = 1
def generate_images(model, test_input):
  generated = model(test_input)
  plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
  list_imgs = [test_input[0], generated[0]]
  title = ['Original', 'Output (generated)']
  for i in range(2):
    plt.subplot(1, 2, i + 1)
    plt.title(title[i])
    plt.imshow(list_imgs[i] * 0.5 + 0.5)
    plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()

# Function to resize tensor to match a target tensor's shape
def resize_tensor_to_target(tensor, target_tensor):
    target_shape = target_tensor.shape
    return tf.image.resize(tensor, [target_shape[1], target_shape[2]])


# Updated training_step function with resizing before concatenation and shape debugging
@tf.function
def training_step(real_x, real_y):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        # Generator G: X -> Y
        # Generator F: Y -> X

        # Generate fake images
        fake_y = generator_g(real_x, training=True)
        cycled_x = generator_f(fake_y, training=True)

        fake_x = generator_f(real_y, training=True)
        cycled_y = generator_g(fake_x, training=True)

        # Identity mapping
        equal_x = generator_f(real_x, training=True)
        equal_y = generator_g(real_y, training=True)

        # Resize tensors to ensure they match before concatenation
        fake_y_resized = resize_tensor_to_target(fake_y, fake_x)
        cycled_y_resized = resize_tensor_to_target(cycled_y, cycled_x)
        equal_y_resized = resize_tensor_to_target(equal_y, equal_x)

        # Print tensor shapes for debugging
        print("Shapes:")
        print("real_x:", real_x.shape, "| real_y:", real_y.shape)
        print("fake_x:", fake_x.shape, "| fake_y_resized:", fake_y_resized.shape)
        print("cycled_x:", cycled_x.shape, "| cycled_y_resized:", cycled_y_resized.shape)
        print("equal_x:", equal_x.shape, "| equal_y_resized:", equal_y_resized.shape)

        # Discriminator outputs
        discriminator_real_x = discriminator_x(real_x, training=True)
        discriminator_fake_x = discriminator_x(fake_x, training=True)
        discriminator_real_y = discriminator_y(real_y, training=True)
        discriminator_fake_y = discriminator_y(fake_y_resized, training=True)

        # Loss calculation
        generator_g_loss = generator_loss(discriminator_fake_y)
        generator_f_loss = generator_loss(discriminator_fake_x)
        cycle_loss_total = cycle_loss(real_x, cycled_x) + cycle_loss(real_y, cycled_y_resized)
        total_generator_g_loss = generator_g_loss + cycle_loss_total + identity_loss(real_y, equal_y_resized)
        total_generator_f_loss = generator_f_loss + cycle_loss_total + identity_loss(real_x, equal_x)
        discriminator_x_loss = discriminator_loss(discriminator_real_x, discriminator_fake_x)
        discriminator_y_loss = discriminator_loss(discriminator_real_y, discriminator_fake_y)

    # Compute gradients
    generator_g_gradients = tape.gradient(total_generator_g_loss, generator_g.trainable_variables)
    generator_f_gradients = tape.gradient(total_generator_f_loss, generator_f.trainable_variables)
    discriminator_x_gradients = tape.gradient(discriminator_x_loss, discriminator_x.trainable_variables)
    discriminator_y_gradients = tape.gradient(discriminator_y_loss, discriminator_y.trainable_variables)

    # Apply gradients
    optimizer_generator_g.apply_gradients(zip(generator_g_gradients, generator_g.trainable_variables))
    optimizer_generator_f.apply_gradients(zip(generator_f_gradients, generator_f.trainable_variables))
    optimizer_discriminator_x.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_x_gradients, discriminator_x.trainable_variables))
    optimizer_discriminator_y.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_y_gradients, discriminator_y.trainable_variables))



# Load InceptionV3 feature extractor from TensorFlow Hub
inception_v3 = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/inception_v3/feature_vector/4')


def get_embeddings(images):
    # Ensuring all images are resized to [299, 299] for compatibility with InceptionV3
    images = tf.image.resize(images, [299, 299])
    images = (images + 1.0) * 127.5  # Scale to [0, 255]
    embeddings = inception_v3(images)

    # Log shape for debugging
    print(f"Embeddings shape: {embeddings.shape}")
    return embeddings



def calculate_fid(real_embeddings, generated_embeddings):
    # Ensure embeddings have the same number of dimensions before calculation
    if real_embeddings.shape != generated_embeddings.shape:
        min_shape = min(real_embeddings.shape[0], generated_embeddings.shape[0])
        real_embeddings, generated_embeddings = real_embeddings[:min_shape], generated_embeddings[:min_shape]

    mu1, sigma1 = np.mean(real_embeddings, axis=0), np.cov(real_embeddings, rowvar=False)
    mu2, sigma2 = np.mean(generated_embeddings, axis=0), np.cov(generated_embeddings, rowvar=False)
    diff = mu1 - mu2
    covmean, _ = sqrtm(sigma1.dot(sigma2), disp=False)

    if np.iscomplexobj(covmean):
        covmean = covmean.real

    fid = diff.dot(diff) + np.trace(sigma1 + sigma2 - 2.0 * covmean)
    return fid


def calculate_is(images, num_splits=10):
    inception_model = InceptionV3(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
    images = preprocess_input(images)
    preds = inception_model.predict(images)
    preds = np.clip(preds, 1e-10, 1.0)

    # Check shape consistency before proceeding
    if preds.ndim != 2:
        print("Prediction shape mismatch. Resizing.")
        preds = preds.reshape(-1, preds.shape[-1])

    scores = []
    split_size = preds.shape[0] // num_splits
    for i in range(num_splits):
        part = preds[i * split_size:(i + 1) * split_size, :]
        py = np.mean(part, axis=0)
        scores.append(np.exp(np.mean([np.sum(p * np.log(p / py)) for p in part])))

    return np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)

# Function to plot FID and IS
def plot_metrics(fid_scores, is_scores):
    epochs = range(1, len(fid_scores) + 1)

    # Plot FID scores
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(epochs, fid_scores, 'bo-', label='FID')
    plt.title('FID Score over Epochs')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('FID Score')
    plt.legend()

    # Plot IS scores
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(epochs, [score[0] for score in is_scores], 'ro-', label='IS Mean')
    plt.fill_between(epochs,
                     [score[0] - score[1] for score in is_scores],
                     [score[0] + score[1] for score in is_scores],
                     color='gray', alpha=0.2, label='IS Std Dev')
    plt.title('Inception Score (IS) over Epochs')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Inception Score')
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()

# Helper function to format time
def format_time(seconds):
    hours = int(seconds // 3600)
    minutes = int((seconds % 3600) // 60)
    seconds = int(seconds % 60)
    return f"{hours}h {minutes}m {seconds}s"

# Modify the train function to use the formatted time output
def train(training_A, training_B, generator_g, generator_f, epochs, sample_A, testing_A, testing_B):
    fid_scores = []
    is_scores = []

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        start = time.time()

        for img_x, img_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip((training_A, training_B)):
            training_step(img_x, img_y)

        clear_output(wait=True)
        generate_images(generator_g, sample_A)

        # Calculate FID and IS
        real_images, generated_images = [], []

        for img_x, img_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip((testing_A, testing_B)).take(100):
            real_images.append(tf.image.resize(img_y, (299, 299)))  # Resize for InceptionV3
            generated_image = generator_g(img_x)
            generated_images.append(tf.image.resize(generated_image, (299, 299)))

        real_images_np = np.concatenate([img.numpy() for img in real_images], axis=0)
        generated_images_np = np.concatenate([img.numpy() for img in generated_images], axis=0)

        # Calculate FID
        real_embeddings = get_embeddings(real_images_np)
        generated_embeddings = get_embeddings(generated_images_np)
        fid_score = calculate_fid(real_embeddings, generated_embeddings)
        fid_scores.append(fid_score)

        # Calculate IS
        is_mean, is_std = calculate_is(generated_images_np)
        is_scores.append((is_mean, is_std))

        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} - FID: {fid_score}, IS: Mean -> {is_mean} STD -> {is_std}')

    # Plot FID and IS
    plot_metrics(fid_scores, is_scores)

    # Save the final models after training in the current directory
    generator_g.save(os.path.join(current_dir, 'generator_g_final.h5'))
    generator_f.save(os.path.join(current_dir, 'generator_f_final.h5'))
    print("Final model saved after training.")

# Example usage:
train(training_A, training_B, generator_g, generator_f, epochs, sample_A, testing_A, testing_B)

I am trying to implement CycleGAN and also calculate the FID and IS score to the model.
How can I modify my model or data pipeline to ensure consistent spatial dimensions for concatenation?
As I can see the model is training and its also giving the output but I am having the problem in the case of FID and IS (as per my thinking goes).
